# XQuery/XPath: How to get calculated value through group by function

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, xquery

I will give an example to better explain myself:

```
<shop>

    <customers>
        <customer id="1">
            <level>A</level>
        </kunde>
        <customer id="2">
            <level>A</level>
        </kunde>
        <customer id="3">
            <level>B</level>
        </kunde>
        <customer id="4">
            <level>C</level>
        </kunde>
        <customer id="5">
            <level>C</level>
        </kunde>
         <customer id="6">
            <level>C</level>
        </kunde>
    </customers>


    <bills>
     <bill id="1">
            <customerId>1</customerId>
            <bposition>
                <price>1</price>
                <amount>1</amount>
            </bposition>
     </bill>
     <bill id="2">
            <customerId>2</customerId>
            <bposition>
                <price>2</price>
                <amount>2</amount>
            </bposition>
            <bposition>
                <price>3</price>
                <amount>2</amount>
            </bposition>

     </bill>

     <bill id ="3">
            <customerId>3</customerId>
            <bposition>
                <price>4</price>
                <amount>1</amount>
            </bposition>
     </bill>

     <bill id ="4">
            <customerId>1</customerId>
            <bposition>
                <price>2</price>
                <amount>2</amount>
            </bposition>
     </bill>

     <bill id ="5">
            <customerId>3</customerId>
            <bposition>
                <price>2</price>
                <amount>2</amount>
            </bposition>
            <bposition>
                <price>5</price>
                <amount>2</amount>
            </bposition>
     </bill>


     <bill id ="6">
            <customerId>4</customerId>
            <bposition>
                <price>1</price>
                <amount>3</amount>
            </bposition>
     </bill>

    <bill id ="7">
            <customerId>5</customerId>
            <bposition>
                <price>5</price>
                <amount>1</amount>
            </bposition>
     </bill>
     <bill id ="8">
            <customerId>6</customerId>
            <bposition>
                <price>2</price>
                <amount>1</amount>
            </bposition>
     </bill>

    </bills>

</shop>
```

I need to get the total revenue and revenue per customer grouped by their level. I probably need distinct-values to only get one level and sort them ascending like A, B, C.

Solution would be then:

```
<level val="A">
<totalRevenue>18</totalRevenue>
<revenueperCustomer>7.5</revenueperCustomer>
</level>

<level val="B">
<totalRevenue>18</totalRevenue>
<revenueperCustomer>18</revenueperCustomer>
</level>

<level val="C">
<totalRevenue>10</totalRevenue>
<revenueperCustomer>3.33</revenueperCustomer>
</level>
```

What I have so far:

```
let $s:= fn:doc('shop.xml')//customers/customer[level = 'A']/[@id],
$price := fn:doc('shop.xml')//bills/bill[customerId = $s]/bposition/price,
$amount := fn:doc('shop.xml')//bills/bill[customerId = $s]/bposition/amount
```

How can I properly group by level and sort it ? Like this

```
let $s:= fn:doc('shop.xml')//customers/customer/level
...
group by $s order by $s ascending
```

I don't know how to group the level and only select the right customer id so I can calculate it with the right values.

Comment: What do you want to select with `fn:doc('shop.xml')//customers/customer[level = 'A']/[@id]`? As for grouping, have you looked at an XQuery 3 introduction (https://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.0#group_by, http://www.datypic.com/books/xquery/) or at the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by?

Comment: I know that there is a group by function but I don't know how do to it properly. Like this let $s:= fn:doc('shop.xml')//customers/customer/level
....
group by $s order by ascending

Comment: I wanted to select the level and get the customer id of this level so I can use this customer id to calculate the price with the amount.

Comment: Why is this tagged `xslt`? Are you looking for an XSLT solution?

Comment: Sorry I removed the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a grouping example:

```
for $bill at $pos in /shop/bills/bill
group by $cat := /shop/customers/customer[@id = $bill/customerId]/level
order by head($pos)
return 
    <level val="{$cat}">{
        let $totalRevenue := sum($bill/bposition/(price * amount))
        return (
        <totalRevenue>{$totalRevenue}</totalRevenue>,
        <revenueperCustomer>{$totalRevenue div count(distinct-values($bill/customerId))}</revenueperCustomer>
        )
    }
    </level>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqteB9

or with a file loaded with the `doc` function

```
declare context item := doc('shop.xml');

for $bill at $pos in /shop/bills/bill
group by $cat := /shop/customers/customer[@id = $bill/customerId]/level
order by head($pos)
return 
    <level val="{$cat}">{
        let $totalRevenue := sum($bill/bposition/(price * amount))
        return (
        <totalRevenue>{$totalRevenue}</totalRevenue>,
        <revenueperCustomer>{$totalRevenue div count(distinct-values($bill/customerId))}</revenueperCustomer>
        )
    }
    </level>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqteB9/2

Comment: If I wanted to open a file again to I have to do it like this. let $a := fn:doc('shop.xml')  for...at..in $a/shop/bills/bill

Comment: As in the previous question, either use `declare context item := doc('shop.xml');` or indeed use a variable `let $shop := doc('shop.xml') for $bill at $pos in $shop/shop/bills/bill group by $cat := $shop/shop/customers/customer[@id = $bill/customerId]/level`

Comment: Thank you but it is weird that when I change it for my local file I get <level val="C"> before <level val="A">. Maybe I need to check the structure again

Comment: Ok I changed it. This also works for me. 
for $bill in /shop/bills/bill
group by $cat := /shop/customers/customer[@id = $bill/customerId]/level
order by $cat ascending.

Comment: I put the `at $pos` and `order by head($pos)` in there as Saxon for instance tends to forget about the original document order when doing XQuery grouping and those two clauses are needed to preserve that order for the result generated. But if you want to order by the grouping key that is fine as well.

Comment: Another question, what if I wanted to divide the total amount through the amount of distinct level ?  Lets say level "A" exists with 5 customers but only 4 customers are in the bills. So I want to divide by 5 which means all existing customers with level "A" and not only the 4 customers in the bill.

Comment: That sounds as if you want to use `div count(/shop/customers/customer[level = $cat])`. That assumes unique `customer` elements, i.e. exactly one for each customer.

Comment: Thank you , you helped me a lot =). Is there a way to make my example more general usable to unknown xml structures ? Like instead of /shop/customers.. you use /*/*...

Comment: Using `/*/*` instead of `/shop/customers` is possible. You can also use `//customer` to select `customer` elements anywhere in the document.